# Automapper / Mapster C# - how do I map collection from specific property?

Tags: c#, mapping, mapster

It is weird but I am stuck with a pretty simple case:

Say I have a class:

```
class Record
{
    public List<Data> Data {get; set;}

    public string OtherProp1 {get; set;}
    public string OtherProp2 {get; set;}
}
```

And I want to map a `List<Model>` from it.
Which is basically:

```
mapper.Map<List<Model>>(Record.Data);
```

But I want Mapster (or Mapper) to be able to make it right from the Record like this:

```
mapper.Map<List<Model>>(Record);
```

So

```
mapper.Map<List<Model>>(Record.Data); // Works easily
mapper.Map<List<Model>>(Record);      // Can't config properly
```

Answer (score 1):

I did find one way with Mapster but it seems like cheating:

```
var config = new TypeAdapterConfig();

config.ForType<Data, Model>();
config.ForType<Record, List<Model>>().MapWith(record => record.Data.Adapt<List<Model>>(config));
```

Because I sort of use Mapster inside of Mapster config )

It must be the way to point the source path like this:

```
config.ForType<Record, List<Model>>().Map(dest => dest, record => record.Data);
```

But all such attempts lead to:

1. Always empty destination collection in Mapster
2. Exceptions in AutoMapper:

*Expression 'dest => dest' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. You can use ForPath, a custom resolver on the child type, or the AfterMap option instead. (Parameter 'lambdaExpression')* -- using .ForMember().

*Only member accesses are allowed. dest => dest (Parameter 'destinationMember')* -- using .ForPath().

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you should use `MapWith` instead of `Map`. In your case it would look something like this:

```cs
TypeAdapterConfig<Record, List<Model>>
    .NewConfig()
    .MapWith(record => record.Data);
```

Here's another example using a predefined list of numbers:

```cs
TypeAdapterConfig<Record, List<int>>
    .NewConfig()
    .MapWith(src => new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 });
```

You can also use `MapWith` to map lists alongside other parent properties, constants, computed values, etc. Take, for instance:

```cs
TypeAdapterConfig<Parent, List<Child>>
    .NewConfig()
    .MapWith(src => src.Children
        .Select(child => new Child()
        {
            ParentId = src.Id,
            Issuer = Constants.Issuer, 
            // Rest of child props...
        })
        .ToList()
    );
```